# How do I not show my presence when I am online in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

How do I hide my presence when I am online in Gmail?

Answer (score 1):

You have to click on **dropdown next to your photo on left hand side**. You will come across one popup shown in image I have attached then click on sign out as status no one able to view you as online. I am considering you are using **standard mode** for gmail mail view.

[image]

Comment: Alterative: Click on "Invisible". This way you still see others online.